# Migrating URLs from WebSphere Traditional Application Server to Liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty

I'm working on migrating a complex application to Liberty and it uses property files that use the WAS URL resource. Is there a way, without re-writing anything in the application so that it will run in Liberty? How can I define the URL in the server.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using jndiURL like this:

```
 <jndiURLEntry jndiName="myFirstJNDIEntry" value='"file:///myDirectory/myConfigFile.properties"' />
```

And access it in code like:

```
@Resource(name="myFirstJNDIEntry")
private URL propsURL;
```

It is discussed in this Redbook [Microservices Best Practices for Java](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg248357.pdf) and in documentation [JNDI URL Entry (jndiURLEntry)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_config_jndiURLEntry.html)